# DatePickerIOS doesn't like Jest mocked Date()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

I'm setting up some Jest testing in my react-native project so i'm setting up snapshots for my components. One of them involves a `DatePicker` (specifically just time) so I needed to mock a consistent `Date()` for the snapshots to match.

The [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios.html#date) for DatePickerIOS indicate it takes a `Date` object in the date prop as I've provided in my `Schedule` component (`new Date()`).

I've made a few attempts at solving this:

```
const constantDate = new Date('Tue Jan 09 2018 14:04:12 GMT-0330 (NST)')

Date = class extends Date {
  constructor() {
        super();
    return constantDate
  }
}
```

&

```
const DATE_TO_USE = new Date('Tue Jan 09 2018 14:04:12 GMT-0330 (NST)');
const _Date = Date;
global.Date = jest.fn(() => DATE_TO_USE);
global.Date.UTC = _Date.UTC;
global.Date.parse = _Date.parse;
global.Date.now = _Date.now;
```

&

```
const mockedDate = new Date(2017, 11, 10)
const originalDate = Date

global.Date = jest.fn(() => mockedDate)
global.Date.setDate = originalDate.setDate
```

It correctly creates & checks the snapshots against each other, but I get the following warning:

```
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `date` of type `Date` supplied to `DatePickerIOS`, expected instance of `_class`.
        in DatePickerIOS (created by DatePicker)
        in DatePicker (created by TimePicker)
        in TimePicker (created by Schedule)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by Schedule)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by Section)
        in Section (created by Schedule)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by Schedule)
        in View (created by View)
        in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
```

Without the mock, the time doesn't match in the snapshot(obviously), but I don't get a warning for the props. Do I need to instantiate every single `Date()` object method or something? What is the cause of this warning & is is possible to fix it?